# Kendo UI Cascading DropDownList without using CascadeFrom

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to have two cascading drop-downs without using CascadeFrom(i.e. manually firing events)?  The reason I don't want to use CascadeFrom is because my parent and child dropdowns both DataValueField is set to DataValueField("ID") due to same property name in both the models as show below.

**MODEL**:

```
 class ParentDropdownModel
    {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class ChildDropdownModel
    {
     public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**VIEW**:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.AutoBind(true)
.Name("ddlParent")        
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("ID")
.OptionLabel("Select a parent...")
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("ReadParent", "Home")))
.Events(e => e.Change("OnParentChanged"))
)

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.AutoBind(false)
.Name("ddlChild")
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("FilterChild", "Home").Data("filterChild")))
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("ID")
.OptionLabel("Select a child...")
)   

<script type="text/javascript">          
    function OnParentChanged(e)
    {            
        var child = $('#ddlChild').data("kendoDropDownList");           
        child.dataSource.read(filterChild());            
    }
    function filterChild()
    {
        var myid = $("#ddlParent").val();            
        return
        {                
            parentID: $("#ddlParent").val()
        };
    }    
</script>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
public ActionResult FilterChild([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string parentID)
{
    // Here is the Problem: parentID is null at run-time
    return Json(dummyData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I finally figured it out with lots of trial and failures.
Basically the code was passing null value for parentID when calling back to FilterChild server method.  All the code is as it is, I just made couple of changes in JavaScript code so now it calls server side method and pass the actual value for parentID parameter.
Here is the **partial** code for the View.

This works but let me know if there is a better way than this.  I am open to learn.

**VIEW:**

```
function OnParentChanged(e)
    {        
         var child = $('#ddlChild').data("kendoDropDownList");     
        child.enable(true);
        var myid = $("#ddlParent").val();
        child.dataSource.read({ parentID: myid });
    }

 //IMPORTANT: NO NEED TO CALL filterChild() FUNCTION, 
 //   Just pass JSON key value pair AS ABOVE.
```

This solution was inspired by this post
[Combobox Cascading need more specific cascadeFrom option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848264/combobox-cascading-need-more-specific-cascadefrom-option/17797423)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this response.

I think that there is a new configuration field for this type of examples.

It is named [CascadingFromField](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-cascadeFromField).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.CascadeFrom("ddlParent")` in the child dropdown if you had a foreign key in the child that related it to its parent:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

class Parent
{
   public (Parent) 
   {
        Children = new HashSet<Child>();
   }

   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set;} // navigation property for MVC
}

class Child
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Column("ParentID")]
   public int ParentId { get; set; } // this is the 'ID' value of the Parent object

   [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
   public virtual Child Child { get; set; } // navigation property for MVC
}

class MainModel
{
    [DisplayName("Child")]
    [ColumnName("ChildID")]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChildID")]
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

This is normally how a database relationship/navigation properties would be set up.  Then you don't need `.Events(e => e.Change("OnParentChanged"))` because it will automatically update the child when the parent is changed.  You do need to ensure that the ID passed into `FilterChild` returns Child items that are filtered based on the parent's ID, though, in that function in your controller.  To avoid that ID being null, you should set your dropdowns to an initial value like "None" on ID #1, instead of having the OptionLabel:

```
@model MainModel

<table><tr><td>Parent:</td><td>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Child.ParentId)
    .AutoBind(true)
    .Name("ddlParent")        
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("ReadParent", "Home")))
    .Value(Model.Child != null ? Model.Child.ParentId.ToString() : "1")
)
</td></tr><tr><td>Child:</td><td>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ChildId)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Name("ddlChild")
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("FilterChild", "Home").Data("filterChild")))
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .CascadeFrom("ddlParent")
    .Value(Model.ChildId != 0 ? Model.ChildId.ToString() : "1")
)   
</td></tr></table>
```

FilterChild would look like this, where you can default the value to that "None" ID if it comes back with no children for that parent:

```
public JsonResult FilterChild(string parentID)
{
    int parentId = int.Parse(parentID);
    List<Child> data = (List<Child>)GetChildrenForParent(parentId);
    if (data.Count() == 0) {
        Child nullChild = new Child();
        nullChild.Id = 1;
        nullChild.ParentId = parentId;
        nullChild.Name = "None";
        data.Add(nullChild);
    }
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet());
}

public IList<Child> GetChildrenForParent(int parentId)
{
    return datacontext.Children.Where(c => c.ParentId == parentId)
            .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
            .ToList();
}
```