# kendo ui dropdownlist- How to do manual Cascading?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, cascade

So im currently trying to adapt some previous code to use with dynamic dropdownlists, the problem seems to be that the cascadeFrom property only takes an id. So i need to use another alternative. Here's my code:

```
       fieldsDiv.html(dynForms + dynFormFields);

       var appendedForms=fieldsDiv.find(".dynamicForms");
       var appendedFormFields= fieldsDiv.find(".dynamicFormFields");


       debugger;
       $(appendedForms).kendoDropDownList({
           dataTextField: "name",
           dataValueField: "id",
           dataSource: {
               type: "json",
               serverFiltering: true,
               transport: {
                   read: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/newlayout/mySearchesDynForms.do"
               }

       }});
       $(appendedFormFields).kendoDropDownList({
           dataTextField: "name",
           dataValueField: "id",
           dataSource: {
               type: "json",
               serverFiltering:true,
               transport: {

                   read:{
                       url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/newlayout/mySearchesFormFieds.do",
                       data:function(){
                           return {formId:  $(appendedForms).val()
                           };
                       }
                   }
               }
           },
           cascadeFrom:  "appendedFormFields"
       });
```

How can i use the dom object matching the second dropdownlist for the cascading?
I've seen this code:

```
    function OnChangeOfParentCombo(e){
 var child = $('#ChildCombo').data().kendoComboBox;
 child.enable(true);
 child.dataSource.read({myFilter:this.value()});}
```

,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13848727/382115), but im not following how do i adapt to my case.

Here's how i think going to be:

```
 $(appendedForms).kendoDropDownList({
       dataTextField: "name",
       dataValueField: "id",
       dataSource: {
           type: "json",
           serverFiltering: true,
           transport: {
               read: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/newlayout/mySearchesDynForms.do"
           },
       change:function(){
             var formId = this.val()
             appendedFormFields.val("").data("kendoDropDownList").text("");
             var formFields = $(appendedFormFields).data("kendoDropDownList");
             formFields.dataSource.read({ formId: formId });               
       }
   }});
   $(appendedFormFields).kendoDropDownList({
       dataTextField: "name",
       dataValueField: "id",
       dataSource: {
           type: "json",
           serverFiltering:true,
           transport: {
               read:{
                   url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/newlayout/mySearchesFormFieds.do",
                   data:function(){
                       return {formId:  $(appendedForms).val()
                       };
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   });
```

Does the property formId from the data function from the second dropdownlist (appendedFormFields) needs to match the `formFields.dataSource.read({ formId: formId });  from the first one change function?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a change event or maybe try an onclose event if it isn't picking up the correct value to "dropdown1"

On that change event get the value of that selected item

```
var advertiserId = $("#AdvertiserDDL").val();
```

clear the contents of "dropdown2" and re read the data source

```
$("#OpportunityDDL").val("").data("kendoDropDownList").text("");

    var opportunity = $("#OpportunityDDL").data("kendoDropDownList");
    opportunity.dataSource.read({ Id: advertiserId });
```

EDIT::
I think it's cleaner to   call a JS function on the change event of the 1st ddl

```
 $(appendedForms).kendoDropDownList({...

   change:function(){
     YourFunction();
}
     YourFunction() {
         var ddlID = appendedForms.val()
         appendedFormFields.val("").data("kendoDropDownList").text("");
         var formFields = $(appendedFormFields).data("kendoDropDownList");
         formFields.dataSource.read({ formId: ddlID });  
       }
```

No you can name that property whatever you want, just make sure the property of the data function matches the parameter in the controller. Just to be safe I make `.dataSource.read({ formId: ddlID });` different variables

Comment: What happens to my data function in the second dropdownList? heres the structure:

transport: {

                       read:{
                           url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}" + "/newlayout/mySearchesFormFieds.do",
                           data:function(){
                               return {formId:  $(appendedForms).val()
                               };
                           }
                       }
                   }

Comment: It should continue to fire

Comment: Hi! both of these code sample should be on the chanve event of the first drop downlist?
I can only test this tomorrow and be back to you then. Thanks..

Comment: Yes, because the 1st dropdown is the one you are "cascading from". Reading it out would be, on 1st dropdown change, get the value that it changed to, clear whatever is in the 2nd dropdown, read the 2nd dropdown's datasource passing the 1st dropdown id as a parameter. You'll notice I'm passing in a parameter to the Read function, this is essentially what the data function does, it brings additional info to the read method. If it's not working it may be because it is trying to do that twice, but I have implemented it like this in projects and haven't had problems

Comment: Hi seems to be working but im getting an error on the the first time the child attempts to get the elements from the server. It seems the value is empty. I put a breakpoint here: 
                               debugger;
                               return {formId:  $(appendedForms).val()
                               };

But it the val() is empty,it does gets all other options thought, but i get a one time error because val() is empty.

Comment: It seems for some reason the second dropdownlist atempts to get data before the first?, don't really understand why its hapenning.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the second ddl to atempt to fetch data before the first one loads?

Comment: Get the data before the first? The 1st dropdown data doesn't change correct?,When the first dropdown changes, are you getting the correct value of the selected item

Comment: Yes, the change works well, i wanted to avoid the use of optionLabels, but i added them on both lists and used the enable property on the second DDL with autoBind to false,  but i would like to avoid this.I would like the second ddl to imediately fetch the data, but in its first atempt the val from first ddl comes empty.

Comment: Set autobind true for the second ddl to get the data immediately

Comment: If i do that i'll get the error, i assume that with the autobind to true it will try to fetch the data on initialization of the widget...still let me try...

Answer (score 2):

I find that using MVVM and HTML declarative binding is much simpler and looks a lot cleaner. Instead of initializing each Kendo UI control via JavaScript functions, you could harness the power of Kendo's declarative binding. It has its limitations, but the technique covers most use-cases. The power is hidden in `data-` attributes and the `kendo.bind()` method.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <select id="types" 
          data-role="dropdownlist" 
          data-option-label=" " 
          data-text-field="name" 
          data-value-field="id" 
          data-bind="source: types, value: type, events: { change: typeChange }">
  </select>
  <select id="items" 
          data-role="dropdownlist" 
          data-option-label=" " 
          data-bind="enabled: type, source: items, value: item">
  </select>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var items = [
  ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'],
  ['Carrot', 'Lettuce', 'Spinach']
];

var vm = kendo.observable({
  type: 0,
  item: '',
  types: [{ id: 1, name: 'Fruits'}, { id: 2, name: 'Vegetables'}],
  items: [],
  typeChange: function(e) {
    var index = e.sender.dataItem().id - 1;
    this.set('items', items[index]);
  }
});

kendo.bind($('body'), vm);
```

Here is an example of the above code that implements **manual** cascading drop-down lists in JSBin: [click here](http://jsbin.com/lubezunu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: This looks interesting, and way more simple but what about remote data?

Comment: In remote data scenarios (using my example) you'll only need to load the `types` array using `$.ajax`. Then, in the `typeChange` method, you would use `$.ajax` to retrieve items based on the selected `id` and set the `items` observable with the returned data.

Comment: Interesting, thanks,can you elaborate more on the lines:

data-bind="source: types, value: type, events: { change: typeChange }">

on both selects?

and

 data-bind="enabled: type, source: items, value: item">

Comment: Check out http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview and then look at the docs for each binding.

Comment: Thanks, i accepted the other user poster because its currently working. But im looking into your answer. Thanks