# Why is CascadeFrom() not doing anything?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I'm really new to Kendo UI, and I'm having problems with `CascadeFrom()` not calling an action on my controller.  Here's the bare bones of my problem:

```
// The parent dropdown
<select id="Testing">
    <option value="0">Vehicle</option>
    <option value="1">Driver</option>
    <option value="2">Trailer</option>
</select>

// The dynamic dropdown                                      
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.VDTId)
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Item")
    .DataSource(ds =>
    {
        ds.Read(c => c.Action("GetVDT", "CompanyVDTUnavailability")
            .Data("getVDTSelection"))
            .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
    .CascadeFrom("Testing"))

// Function to allow Kendo to pass a value to 
// the type parameter of my GetVDT action.
function getVDTSelection() {
    return {
        type: parseInt($("#Testing").val())
    };
}
```

The action is being called when the page first loads, and returns the correct data.  The problem is, if I then make a selection from the `Testing` dropdown, the action is never invoked on the controller (I've verified this using a breakpoint on the action), meaning the dynamic dropdown never gets updated.

Looking through the official example, and other questions around SO, I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

**Edit**: I've tried Petur's solution below by changing the parent dropdown to the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Type)
    .Name("Testing")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .BindTo(Model.UnavailabilityTypes))
```

This binds the parent dropdown correctly, but no longer invokes the controller action for the cascading dropdown even when the page first loads.  Any suggestions?

Controller action signature as requested:

```
public JsonResult GetVDT(CompanyUnavailabilityType type)
```

Where `CompanyUnavailabilityType` is an enum.

Comment: What is the parameter definition of your read action. It must be called `type` if that's how you are returning it in the js function. Try getting rid of a parseInt, I've never had to use it in this scenario. One time my method expected a Guid, but it wouldn't work. So I made it expect a string and did `return {
        type: " " + ("#Testing").val()
    };

Comment: @CSharper Thanks for the comment.  I've added the method signature, but I've tried both with and without using `parseInt` and I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Petur and C Sharper were on the right track with the problem.

1. I did need to build the dropdown using `Html.Kendo.DropDownList()` (I've just verified this after getting the solution to work.)
2. The method signature on the controller was a problem, but only because I'd had old testing methods left on there, leading to an ambiguous call.

The major difficulty for me was that nothing was being reported in the debugger, so diagnosing the problem was a pain.  In the end, I used the Network tab of the Firefox web developer tools to ensure the Ajax request was indeed being sent, and it was.  Inspecting that request showed it was leading to an ambiguous call on the controller.

Also, to clear up comments from C Sharper's answer:

1. The `parseInt()` call is not required.
2. The call will correctly map to an enum on the server-side, meaning the method signature I posted in my question is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo DropDownList can cascade only from another Kendo DropDownList/ComboBox. Turn the first widget into kendo DropDownList and it should start working properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this hasn't worked for me.  The parent DropDownList is being correctly populated from my model, I've double-checked to ensure its id is `Testing` and nothing.  In fact, by changing it to be a Kendo DropDownList, it doesn't even invoke the controller action when it first loads any more.  Do you have any idea what I may have done wrong?

Comment: Nevermind - I've managed to solve it.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Only problem I can think of is if AutoBind option of the child DDL is not set to false like explained in the docs.

Comment: @JohnH Please can you share what did you do to fix this issue. I am facing the same.

Comment: Lol this question was asked like 6 years ago, it would be amazing if he remembers what Kendo is :D

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `getVDTSelection()` is returning an int or string value not an Enum value. Change your method sig to an int if not, try a string and the method described in my comment

```
public JsonResult GetVDT(int type)
{
   //AllowGet might be needed as well
   return Json(jsonObjx,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Edit:
You can also try to Manually force the ddl to cascade. Ditch `CascadeFrom` and do it manually.

```
function OnChangeOfParentDDL(e){

    var parentValue =  $("#ParentDDL").val();

    $("#ChildDDL").val("").data("kendoDropDownList").text("");//clear it out

    var child = $("#ChildDDL").data("kendoDropDownList");
    child.dataSource.read({ type : parentValue });    
}
```

Comment: This was my suspicion earlier, when I was building the dropdown manually, but I hadn't tried that again since Petur's answer.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work either.  I've tried with both a `string` parameter and an `int` parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615366/kendo-ui-dropdownlist-how-to-do-manual-cascading

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I couldn't your solution to work, but you did point me in the right direction.