# Kendo MVC3 Cascading ComboBoxFor/DropDownListFor Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm having a problem with a Cascading DropDownListFor. I was upgrading a page from the Telerik 2012 MVC Extensions to the UI for ASP.NET MVC. While every other page has been a breeze, the one page with the cascading drop down lists has been a nightmare.

The Controller is called "SalesOrder." Here is the behavior I want from my Kendo drop down lists:

1. The SourceSystem drop down list (DDL) is the first one to load.
2. The Consignee DDL must populate based on the value in the SourceSystem DDL.
3. There is a third DDL that must populate based on the value in the Consignee DDL, but I think that if I can get the Consignee DDL working, I can get this third DDL working too.

Here are the drop down lists and javascript.

```
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.SourceSystem)
                    .BindTo(ViewBag.SourceSystemShortNames)
                    .DataTextField("SourceSystemDisplayName")
                    .DataValueField("SourceSystemId")
                    .Value(Model.SourceSystem)
                )


                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Consignee)
                    .CascadeFrom("SourceSystem")
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetConsignees", "SalesOrder")
                                .Data("GetSourceSystemVal");
                        });
                    })
                    .Value(Model.Consignee)
                    .DataTextField("ConsigneeDisplayName")
                    .DataValueField("ConsigneeId")
                    .AutoBind(false)
                )

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSourceSystemVal() {
        return {
            SourceSystem: $("#SourceSystem").val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

Here is the GetConsignees in the SalesOrder Controller which is SUPPOSED to get consignees when the SourceSystem changes.

```
            public JsonResult GetConsignees(string SourceSystem)
            {
                var consignees = dbContext.Consignees.AsQueryable();

                var returnConsignees = consignees
    .Where(r => r.SourceSystemShortName == SourceSystem)
    .Select(r => new { ConsigneeId = r.Consignee1, ConsigneeDisplayName = r.Consignee1 });

                return Json(returnConsignees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

The SourceSystem drop down list populates just fine because it is set as a ViewBag object when the page loads. When the page loads, I even get a call to ~/SalesOrder/GetConsigness/?SourceSystem=TEST. I verified that I get records in the returnConsignees variable, and I always get 1 with the TEST SourceSystem as expected. However, the only DDL that populates is the SourceSystem list. When I change the value in the SourceSystem list, I don't even see a new call to the GetConsignees method. I need the Consignee DDL to change when the SourceSystem changes, so this is a problem.

I don't understand why I'm having so much trouble cascading here. Is there something I'm missing? Am I thinking about this incorrectly? Please Help!

Comment: Is `$(#"SourceSystem").val()` always a string? It looks like your populating it with `SourceSystemId` property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310479/why-is-cascadefrom-not-doing-anything/24313850#24313850

Comment: Yes, $(#"SourceSystem").val() will always be a string.